# target mutiple classes above (this) in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've built a simple dropdown menu to replace some html select menus like so:

```
$('html, .currentPage').click(function() { 
    $('.currentMenu').slideUp('fast'); 
});

$('.currentPage').click(function(e){        
    if(!$(this).next().is(":visible")) { 
        $(this).next().stop().slideDown('fast'); 
    }
    e.stopPropagation(); 
});

$(".currentMenu li").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".currentPage").html($(this).text());
});
```

However, if I were to have more than one menu, the final part:

```
$(".currentMenu li").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".currentPage").html($(this).text());
});
```

will occur on both menus. How can I target the ".currentPage" class for that specific menu only?

HTML:

```
                        <div class="menuWrap font">
                            <div class="currentPage">Trebuchet MS</div>
                            <div class="currentMenu">
                              <ul>
                                <li>Arial</li>
                                <li>Helvetica</li>
                                <li>Droid Sans</li>
                                <li>Trebuchet MS</li>
                                <li>Georgia</li>
                                <li>Droid Serif</li>
                              </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="menuWrap fontSize">
                            <div class="currentPage">12pt</div>
                            <div class="currentMenu">
                              <ul>
                                <li>9pt</li>
                                <li>10pt</li>
                                <li>11pt</li>
                                <li>12pt</li>
                                <li>13pt</li>
                              </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: I've updated my answer now that you've posted your HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options. The first is to traverse the DOM to find the nearest `.currentPage` element from `.currentMenu li`. Given your HTML structure, this should work:

```
$(".currentMenu li").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest(".currentMenu").prev().html($(this).text());
});
```

The second option is to put this code into a plugin which you apply to an element, so you always know the context in which to select elements in.

Comment: @HackedByChinese gave the easiest solution, but you gave a better one. Some kind of encapsulation really should be done here, whether via a jQuery plugin or the instantiation of a class. However, this is probably getting a bit advanced for the OP at this point.

Comment: Excellent. Always the simplest things that catch me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

OK, based on your updated question. .currentMenu and .currentPage are siblings. So you can navigate to the parent element, then drill down to the currentPage. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DuPuJ/

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to be responding to that change? Would you mind posting it on a JS fiddle? Thanks

Comment: OK, that changes things a bit. Here's an updated answer with sample.